# Syntax - How to combine Binding with Localization?

Tags: binding, localization, maui

I need to combine localization with binding. I have the following xml:

```
<Label Text="{Binding TravelOrder.StartDate, StringFormat='Start Date: {0:d}'}" />
```

I would like to have the string format localized, i.e. instead of "Start Date" to have, for instance, for French, "Date de debut".

How can I put something like {x:Static res:AppRes.StartDate} inside my StringFormat value ?

I have tried to write something like

```
Text="{Binding TravelOrder.StartDate, StringFormat='{x:Static res:AppRes.StartDate}: {0:d}'}" />
```

but clearly that doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: use a ValueConverter, or [FormattedText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#formatted-text) which will allow you to break your Label into multiple spans with the static translated text and the DateTime separated

Comment: Which countries do you want to localize, only French? or more? And please provide a format example.